# Armazenamento de imagens em mongodb

Tags: mongodb, react, .net-core

Estou desenvolvendo um app mobile em react em que existirão varios perfis, possuindo até no máximo 5 fotos cada.
Nossa api atualmente é feita em aspnet core 2.0 e utilizamos o mongodb como banco de dados.
A minha dúvida é a seguinte, qual é a melhor forma de realizar esta implementação considerando que essas fotos serão mostradas praticammente toda vez que o perfil de um usuário for carregado?
Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Tem como salvar BLOB no MongoDB?

Comment: tem como salvar dados em binário sim

Comment: Algum problema em guardar apenas o endereço da imagem em forma de string?

Comment: Não é nada aconselhável armazenar imagens no BD. Principalmente se terá grande acesso. Procure mais sobre o assunto, pois tem bastante conteúdo sobre isso.

Comment: Cria uma pasta com indexação de arquivo, apos a criação da pasta faça upload dos arquivos para ela e apenas salve o caminho da foto no banco. Uma forma bem mais simples e econômica.